# Flutter Decorate Input Field from External Dart File

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout

I am trying to style a textformfield by having the decorations outside the widget and imported via dot notation. I have created a new class `constants.dart` and saved my decorations in a `const variable`.

Here's my form code:

```
 TextFormField(
          keyboardType: TextInputType.number,
          decoration: textInputDecoration
              .copyWith(labelText: 'Principal', hintText: 'Principal Value'),
          onChanged: (value){
            setState(() {

            });
          },
        ),
```

and the `constants.dart` file where I am facing an issue with adding rounded corners to the border:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

const textInputDecoration = InputDecoration(
   enabledBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
   borderSide: BorderSide(
   color: Colors.indigo,
   width: 1.5
 )
),
border: OutlineInputBorder(
  borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(5.0) // evaluation of this constant expression throws an exception
 ),
errorBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
  borderSide: BorderSide(
  color: Colors.redAccent,
  width: 2.2
 )
),
focusedBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
  borderSide: BorderSide(
    color: Colors.brown,
    width: 1.5
  )
)
```

);

adding that file directly to the form field shows no errors but having it external doesn't seem to work and I can't figure out what the issue is here. I have other fields and trying to reduce the bloat in my form widget. Any help would be appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: Are you sure that you are importing the constants package and you don't have any other textInputDecoration defined in this file?

Comment: Yes, but I will leave this issue and ask you another question from my observation - Two form fields and when the second one is opened, it flashes a yellow error - BOTTOM OVERFLOWED BY 75 PIXELS, keep in mind the keyboard is open. Will this show up for real users and how to correct this? Thanks

Comment: Yep, you should fix it. Maybe you need a scrollview, but if you need help ask for it in different question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason why your constant doesn't work is that Dart doesn't allow `const` to be mutable, this is one of the difference between `final` and `const`. Dart will actually check `const` on compile time.

Interesting, this might be a bug in Flutter...

```
/// Creates a border radius where all radii are [Radius.circular(radius)].
BorderRadius.circular(double radius) : this.all(
  Radius.circular(radius),
);
```

It doesn't return a constant value, but

```
/// Creates a border radius where all radii are [radius].
const BorderRadius.all(Radius radius) : this.only(
  topLeft: radius,
  topRight: radius,
  bottomLeft: radius,
  bottomRight: radius,
);
```

does, where `BorderRadius.circular` is just a shortcut.

Solution: just use `BorderRadius.all`:

```
border: OutlineInputBorder(
  borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(5.0))
),
```

Comment: I checked whether this is a bug - well it's not, but the reason is quite interesting. It comes down to determining whether `double` is a constant or not.

Comment: Thanks, I used a listview for the zigzag flashing on the screen. Answer accepted